# Facebook Graph API can't get shared post content but the original

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the content of the a facebook post using facebook graph API v2.9. I get error in the case of my friend shares a video from another page.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/743711040_10155091021136041?fields=source,created_time&access_token=[user_access_token]

Where the '743711040_10155091021136041' is [userid_postid] and the user access token has the the following permissions:

```
"public_profile", "user_friends", "user_posts", "email"
```

The response I get is:

```
error: {
message: "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '743711040_10155091021136041' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
type: "GraphMethodException",
code: 100,
fbtrace_id: "BF9o+18whmD"
}
```

But when I try with the original page post that my friend has shared:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/960234257424791_1318359071612306?fields=source,created_time&access_token=[user_access_token]

Where the '960234257424791_1318359071612306' is [pageid_postid] I get a success response:

```
source: "https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-2/18524911_304316830006313_7455758837228765184_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjMzMSwicmxhIjo2NTgsInZlbmNvZGVfdGFnIjoic3ZlX3NkIn0%3D&_nc_pt=1&rl=331&vabr=184&oh=3b3077d9a1e2b645f1531d6562ee4da8&oe=5942A4AF",
created_time: "2017-05-15T11:24:41+0000",
id: "960234257424791_1318359071612306"
```

Please tell me if I'm missing something? Need another permission? Or what could be the problem?

**Update**

If it is really impossible to get post details of a friend that hasn't authorize my app, then can I at least get the original post_id of the page post that my friend has shared? This will be very helpful.

Comment: The `access_token` that you are using is it your access token or your friend's? If it's yours then you will not be able to view your friend's posts. If you want to see your friends posts then your friend should provide you with his `access_token` with `user_posts' permission.

Comment: Your app would need `user_posts` permission from your friend to be able to read their post.

Comment: But I'm using my own `access_token` to get a post of my friend which can by default be seen from my facebook account !!

Comment: Information being public on FB UI doesn't mean that it's public with the APIs. Do read the docs.

Comment: @RahulSharma thanks for clarifying the issue, now I see. Would you please check my update?

Comment: @HamzehSoboh please specify what exactly is it that you want to do here. It will be more useful in resolving your problem.

Comment: @RahulSharma What I want is, if post type was `video` then I need to fetch the direct video link (`source`) then the user will be able to download it.

Comment: If you have the `page_id` then get all those posts of the page that have the `type: video` and then get the `source` field for that post. This `source` will be the direct link to the video.